# Prove the following Combinatorial identity

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

For any m $\ge$ 1. Prove that
$$\sum_{j=0}^m\frac{1}{j+1}{m \choose j} = \frac{1}{m+1}(2^{m+1} -1 )$$

Attempt: I tried using subsets after rearranging the equation. Then even though the R.H.S gives the no of substes of n+1 excluding empty. I am unable to get a interpretation for L.H.S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac1{j+1}\binom{m}j=\frac1{m+1}\binom{m+1}{j+1}$$

(This is an identity worth knowing; it comes up quite often.)

Comment: How to prove it. I have never seen this

Comment: @Amrita: One way is to rewrite the binomial coefficients in terms of factorials. $$\binom{m+1}{j+1}=\frac{(m+1)!}{(j+1)!(m-j)!}=\frac{m+1}{j+1}\binom{m}j$$

Answer (score 1):

Start with
$$ (1+x)^m=\sum_{j=0}^{m}{m\choose j}x^j $$
and integrate both sides from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Sorry should I integrate with respect to m.  The RHS ${m \choose j}$ is constant. How do you do for $x^j$ . My calculus is weak

Comment: No, integrate with respect to $x$. $\int_0^1x^j\;dx=\frac{1}{j+1}$, and $\int_0^1(1+x)^m\;dx=\frac{2^{m+1}-1}{m+1}$.